# Split file by vector of line numbers

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a large file, about 10GB. I have a vector of line numbers which I would like to use to split the file. Ideally I would like to accomplish this using command-line utilities. As a regex:

File:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9 
10 11 12 
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

Vector of line numbers:

```
2 5
```

Desired output:

File 1:

```
1 2 3
```

File 2:

```
4 5 6
7 8 9 
10 11 12
```

File 3:

```
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
csplit -z file 2 5
```

or if you want regexp:

```
csplit -z file /2/ /5/
```

With the default values, the  output files will be named `xxnn` where `nn` starts at `00` and is incremented by 1.

N.B. The `-z` option prevents empty elided files.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -v v="2 5" '       # space-separated vector if indexes
BEGIN {
    n=split(v,t)         # reshape vector to a hash
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        a[t[i]]
    i=1                  # filename index
}
{
    if(NR in a) {        # file record counter in the vector
        close("file" i)  # close previous file
        i++              # increase filename index
    }
    print > ("file" i)   # output to file
}' file
```

Sample output:

```
$ cat file2
4 5 6
7 8 9 
10 11 12
```

Answer (score 3):

Very slightly different from James's and kvantour's solutions: passing the vector to awk as a "file"

```sh
vec="2 5"

awk '
    NR == FNR {nr[$1]; next}
    FNR == 1 {filenum = 1; f = FILENAME "." filenum}
    FNR in nr {
        close(f)
        f = FILENAME "." ++filenum
    }
    {print > f}
' <(printf "%s\n" $vec) file
```

```sh
$ ls -l file file.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 glenn glenn 48 Jul 17 10:02 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 glenn glenn  7 Jul 17 10:09 file.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 glenn glenn 23 Jul 17 10:09 file.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 glenn glenn 18 Jul 17 10:09 file.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little `awk` that does the trick for you:

```
awk -v v="2 5" 'BEGIN{v=" 1 "v" "}
                index(v," "FNR" ") { close(f); f=FILENAME "." (++i) }
                { print > f }' file
```

This will create files of the form: `file.1`, `file.2`, `file.3`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've gone totally mental this morning, and I came up with ***a Sed program (with functions, loops, and all) to generate a Sed script*** to make what you want.

Usage:

- put the script in a file (e.g. `make.sed`) and `chmod +x` it;
- then use it as the script for this Sed command `sed "$(./make.sed <<< '1 4')" inputfile`¹

Note that `./make.sed <<< '1 4'` generates the following sed script:

```
1,1{w file.1
be};1,4{w file.2
be};1,${w file.3
be};:e
```

¹ Unfortunately I misread the question, so my script works taking the line number of the *last* line of each block that you want to write to file, so your `2 5` has to be changed to `1 4` to be fed to my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sed -Ef

###########################################################
# Main
# make a template sed script, in which we only have to increase
# the number of each numbered output file, each of which is marked
# with a trailing \x0
b makeSkeletonAndMarkNumbers
:skeletonMade

# try putting a stencil on the rightmost digit of the first marked number on
# the line and loop, otherwise exit
b stencilLeastDigitOfNextMarkedNumber
:didStencilLeastDigitOfNextMarkedNumber?
t nextNumberStenciled
b exit

# continue processing next number by adding 1
:nextNumberStenciled
b numberAdd1
:numberAdded1

# try putting a stencil on the rightmost digit of the next marked number on
# the line and loop, otherwise we're done with the first marked number, we can
# clean its marker, and we can loop
b stencilNextNumber
:didStencilNextNumber?
t nextNumberStenciled
b removeStencilAndFirstMarker
:removeStencilAndFirstMarkerDone
b stencilLeastDigitOfNextMarkedNumber

###########################################################
# puts a \n on each side of the first digit marked on the right by \x0
:stencilLeastDigitOfNextMarkedNumber
tr
:r
s/([0-9])\x0;/\n\1\n\x0;/1
b didStencilLeastDigitOfNextMarkedNumber?

###########################################################
# makes desired sed script skeleton from space-separated numbers
:makeSkeletonAndMarkNumbers
s/$/ $/
s/([1-9]+|\$) +?/1,\1{w file.0\x0;be};/g
s/$/:e/
b skeletonMade

###########################################################
# moves the stencil to the next number followed by \x0
:stencilNextNumber
trr
:rr
s/\n(.)\n([^\x0]*\x0[^\x0]+)([0-9])\x0/\1\2\n\3\n\x0/
b didStencilNextNumber?

###########################################################
# +1 with carry to last digit on the line enclosed in between two \n characters
:numberAdd1
#i\
#\nprima della somma:
#l
:digitPlus1
h
s/.*\n([0-9])\n.*/\1/
y/0123456789/1234567890/
G
s/(.)\n(.*)\n.\n/\2\n\1\n/
trrr
:rrr
/[0-9]\n0\n/s/(.)\n0\n/\n\1\n0/
t digitPlus1
# the following line can be problematic for lines starting with number
/[^0-9]\n0\n/s/(.)\n0\n/\n\1\n10/
b numberAdded1

###########################################################
# remove stencil and first marker on line
:removeStencilAndFirstMarker
s/\n(.)\n/\1/
s/\x0//
b removeStencilAndFirstMarkerDone

###########################################################
:exit
# a bit of post processing the `w` command has to be followed
# by the filename, then by a newline, so we change the appropriate `;`s to `\n`.
s/(\{[^;]+);/\1\n/g
```